# How to properly organize C# application design for muli-objects JSON?

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have problem with architectural problem for my C# application. I need to have the following JSON:

```
{data:{lat:22,lng:33}, error:{code:0,description:""}}
```

I'm trying to implement this JSON structure with these classes:

```
public class Response
{
    public object Data { get; set; }
    public object Error { get; set; }

    public Response()
    {
        Error = new ErrorsManager();
    }
}

public class Coordinates : Response
{
    public double Lat { get; set; }
    public double Lng { get; set; }
}
```

I can set values for ***Error*** without any problems. But how to set values for ***Data*** I can't understand. Can anybody suggest proper solution for this situation? I know that this problem can be solved with **extends** in Java. Can I use something similar in C#?

**Update:** I'd like to have common root objects in JSON - data and error. But data object can have different context like: coordinates, user data, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would set Data to an instance of coordinates. That is something like this:

```
public class Response
{
    public object Data { get; set; }
    public object Error { get; set; }

    public Response()
    {
        Error = new ErrorsManager();
        Data = new Coordinates();
    }
}

public class Coordinates {
    public double Lat { get; set; }
    public double Lng { get; set; }
}
```

You might think about creating strongly typed versions of Response meaning something like this:

```
public class Response
{
    public Coordinates Data { get; set; }
    public ErrorsManager Error { get; set; }

    public Response()
    {
        Error = new ErrorsManager();
        Data = new Coordinates();
    }
}
```

If you have different response types, you might want to have a base class defining only Error and the subclasses adding a new property. I assume you're using something like [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) to serialize / deserialize.

You could be generic:

```
public class Response<T> where T : new() {
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public ErrorsManager Error { get; set; }

    public Response() {
        Error = new ErrorsManager();
        Data = new T();
    }
}

public class Coordinates {
    /* left away */
}
```

Usage:

```
var response = new Response<Coordinates>();
response.Data.Lat = 0.01;
// whatever you like
```

Comment: You know I'd like to have common root objects in JSON - data and error. But data object can have different context like: coordinates, user data, etc.

Comment: I commonly go with different response classes for one reason: It's much more unlikely I take one response type for another. You could set Data from outside the class (in the code creating the response) to any serializable object you want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

c#:

```
String JSON = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(
    new { data = new { lat = 22; lng = 33; }; error = new {code = 0; description=String.Empty;}; }
);
```

Or:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

    public class myResponse
    {
        public Coordinates data;
        public Error error;

        public myResponse()
        {
            data = new Coordinates();
            error = new Error();
        }
    }

    public class Coordinates
    {
        public double lat;
        public double lng;
    }

    public class Error
    {
        public int code;
        public String description;
    }

    var resp = new myResponse();
    resp.data.lat = 0.3453453453;
    resp.data.lng = 0.3453453453;
    resp.error.code = 0;
    resp.error.description = "Description of error";

    String JSON = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(resp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create type safe classes instead of declaring them as object

```
public class Response
{
    public Coordinates Data { get; set; }
    public Error Error { get; set; }
}

public class Error
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class Coordinates 
{
    public double Lat { get; set; }
    public double Lng { get; set; }
}
```

You can deserialize the json string as

```
string jsonStr = @"{data:{lat:22,lng:33}, error:{code:0,description:""aaa""}}";

var jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(jsonStr); //Json.Net
```

or

```
var jObj2 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Response>(jsonStr);
```

---

You can also go totally **dynamic** way using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) without declaring any of these classes

```
dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonStr); 
Console.WriteLine(dynObj.data.lat);
Console.WriteLine(dynObj.error.description);
```

Comment: In your 1st sample Coordinates would have Data, Error, Lat and Lng?

Comment: @Sascha I can't understand what you ask.

Comment: If the class Coordinate inherits from Response it will also inherit Data and Error -> so Coordinate's properties will be Error, Data, Lat and Lng while they should only be Lat & Lng. And I think it's at least a very interesting construct to have a class inheriting from Response as a type definition for a property in the base class.

Comment: @Sascha there is no inheritence, no base class in my code. I still don't get your point. Ohh I see. It is a typo

Comment: public class Coordinates : Response ? (At least before your edit...)

Comment: @Sascha sorry it must be left there somehow... (Yea I found it, it is copied over from OP's code)